# How do I create, save, and call new instances of a class in java using a users input?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that calculates a patients charges. This program is supposed to get user input.

I have a class called Assignment4 that is getting and setting information from another class called Patient and another called Procedure. The ONLY objective I am stuck on is trying to create separate instances of the Procedure class using a users input. I want to then loop through and display the information from each of those instances and show the information from each procedure that the user has input.

I have failed pretty miserably at trying to use an array to accomplish this, I have tried so many different things

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Assignment4{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Patient patientInfo = new Patient();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Procedure procedureInfo = new Procedure();
        java.util.ArrayList procedures = new java.util.ArrayList();

        //Get information from user and immediately set patient class parameters
        System.out.println("Welcome to your account charges.");

        //First name
        System.out.println("Please enter your first name.");
        String firstName = input.next();
        patientInfo.setFirstName(firstName);
        //Middle name
        System.out.println("Please enter your middle name.");
        String middleName = input.next();
        patientInfo.setMiddleName(middleName);
        //Last name
        System.out.println("Please enter your last name.");
        String lastName = input.next();
        patientInfo.setLastName(lastName);
        //Phone number
        System.out.println("Please enter your phone number.");
        String phoneNumber = input.next();
        patientInfo.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        //EMC name
        System.out.println("Please enter your emergency contact's full name.");
        String emerContName = input.next();
        patientInfo.setEmerContName(emerContName);
        //EMC number
        System.out.println("Please enter your emergency contact's phone number.");
        String emerContPhoneNumber = input.next();
        patientInfo.setEmerContPhoneNumber(emerContPhoneNumber);

        //Get information from user and immediately set procedure class parameters
        //Num of procedures
        System.out.println("How many procedures are you having?");
        int numOfProcedures = input.nextInt();
        procedureInfo.setNumOfProcedures(numOfProcedures);
        //Loop according to how many procedures
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfProcedures; i++) {
            //Procedure name
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of your procedure.");
            String procedureName = input.next();            
            procedureInfo.setProcedureName(procedureName);
            //Procedure date
            System.out.println("Please enter the date of your procedure.");
            String procedureDate = input.next();
            procedureInfo.setProcedureDate(procedureDate);
            //Doctors name
            System.out.println("Please enter your doctor's name.");
            String doctorName = input.next();
            procedureInfo.setDoctorName(doctorName);
            //Charge for procedure random from 100 to 10000

            //Store procedure 1, 2, etc..

        }
        //Display summary
        //Display patients information once
        System.out.println("\n---Acccount Details---.\n");
        //Patient name, Number
        System.out.println("First name : " + patientInfo.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("Middle name : " + patientInfo.getMiddleName());
        System.out.println("Last name : " + patientInfo.getLastName());
        System.out.println("Phone number : " + patientInfo.getPhoneNumber());
        //EMC Name, Number
        System.out.println("Emergency contact name : " + patientInfo.getEmerContName());
        System.out.println("Emergency contact phone number : " + patientInfo.getEmerContPhoneNumber());
        //Loop through displaying each procedure
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfProcedures; i++) {
            //Procedure name
            //Procedure date
            //Doctors name
            //Charge for specific procedure
            //Total charges
        }
        
        input.close();
        
        public void create(){
            procedures.add(new Procedure(procedureName, procedureDate, doctorName, charge));
        }
        
    
    }
    
}
```

Procedure Class

```
    //Variables
    private String procedureName;
    private String procedureDate;
    private String doctorName;
    private double charge;
    private int numOfProcedures;
    private String input;
    
    
    
    public Procedure() {
        
    }
    
    public Procedure(String procedureName, String procedureDate, String doctorName, double charge, int numOfProcedures){
        this.procedureName = procedureName;
        this.procedureDate = procedureDate;
        this.doctorName = procedureName;
        this.charge = charge;
        this.numOfProcedures = numOfProcedures;
    }

    public Procedure(String input){
        this.input = input;
    }

    public String getInput(){
        return input;
    }
    /**
     * @return the procedureName
     */
    public String getProcedureName() {
        return procedureName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the procedureDate
     */
    public String getProcedureDate() {
        return procedureDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return the doctorName
     */
    public String getDoctorName() {
        return doctorName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the charge
     */
    public double getCharge() {
        return charge;
    }

    /**
     * @return the numOfProcedures
     */
    public int getNumOfProcedures() {
        return numOfProcedures;
    }

    /**
     * @param procedureName the procedureName to set
     */
    public void setProcedureName(String procedureName) {
        this.procedureName = procedureName;
    }

    /**
     * @param procedureDate the procedureDate to set
     */
    public void setProcedureDate(String procedureDate) {
        this.procedureDate = procedureDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param doctorName the doctorName to set
     */
    public void setDoctorName(String doctorName) {
        this.doctorName = doctorName;
    }

    /**
     * @param charge the charge to set
     */
    public void setCharge(double charge) {
        this.charge = charge;
    }

    /**
     * @param numOfProcedures the numOfProcedures to set
     */
    public void setNumOfProcedures(int numOfProcedures) {
        this.numOfProcedures = numOfProcedures;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Procedure [procedureName=" + procedureName + ", procedureDate=" + procedureDate + ", doctorName="
                + doctorName + ", charge=" + charge + ", numOfProcedures=" + numOfProcedures + "]";
    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please note that this site is not a debugging service. Copy-pasting large slabs of code into the question and asking us to debug it is off-topic. However, we can help you with *specific* questions about small *parts* of your code (a few lines), ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to narrow its focus and remove all code not directly relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an arraylist, but if you have a fixed size, you can just use an array. But it needs defined *after* you actual know the size.

Then, just create and store an instance each time over the loop rather than only one at the start of the main method

```
    System.out.println("How many procedures are you having?");
    int numOfProcedures = input.nextInt();

    Procedure[] procedures = new Procedure[numOfProcedures];

    //Loop according to how many procedures
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfProcedures; i++) {
        procedures[i] = new Procedure();

        //Procedure name
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of your procedure.");
        procedures[i].setProcedureName(input.nextLine());
        
        // ...
    }
```

Note that the Procedure class is a single instance, therefore storing  `numOfProcedures` as part of it doesn't make sense. You can use `procedures.length` later to get that information.